# python matploblib how do i add numbers on top of my barchart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering how do i add annotation to my barchart to make it display the readings above. Any help would be much appreciated! also if theres any tips on how to style my barchart , would be appreciated!. thank you so much.!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

title = "traffic facilities"
titlelen = len(title)
print("{:*^{titlelen}}".format(title, titlelen=titlelen+6))
print()

data = np.genfromtxt(
    "data/traffic-facilities.csv",
    dtype=[int,"U100",int],
    delimiter=",",
    names=True)

years = np.unique(data["year"])
facility = np.unique(data["facility"])
trafficLight = data[data["facility"]=="Traffic Lights"]["number"]
erpGantries = data[data["facility"]=="ERP Gantries"]["number"]



plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
avgtrafficfac = []
labels = []
for c in facility: # Note the change from distances to modes here
    labels.append(c)
    mu = np.mean(data[data["facility"]==c]["number"])
    avgtrafficfac.append(mu)

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 6))
bar0 = plt.bar(labels,avgtrafficfac,color="blue",alpha=0.25,linewidth="2",edgecolor="black")
plt.xlabel("Traffic facilities")[enter image description here][1]
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.ylabel("Amount of traffic facilities")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your_number = 5

for i in plt.patches:
    plt.text(i.get_x(), i.get_height()+1, your_number)
```

Take a look at matplotlib.patches to get the dimesnions (get_x and get_heigth) of your bars.

Add text at desired location.

Hope this helps you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example on the matplotlib site here: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html

In that example, they use the following function:

```
def autolabel(rects):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')
```

Your `bar0` variable should have a patches attribute containing the rectangles that you should be able to pass into that function, and you should be able to modify it to your liking.